# N1Ql query for data in json in array

Tags: java, json, sql++

I am looking for n1ql query which retries the whole json satisfying condition in array in json

{
   "lmrNumber": "0000063",
   "weight":"20",
   "loadNumber": "SHREF",
   "lineHaulLmr": [
      {
         "lineHaulResponsibileSite":"4059",
         "lineHaulArrivalDate": "01/06/2017",
         "lineHaulDepartureDate": "01/06/2017",
         "lineHaulDepartureTime": "21:00",
         "lineHaulArrivalTime": "22:30",
         "lineHaulStatus":"PENDING",
         "driverDetails": {
            "driverName":"",
            "sloc":"3719",
            "eloc":"3701",
            "jobNumber":""
         }
     }
   ]
}

The condition is query should retrieve the data which has got sloc as `4059` in array.

I tried in this way but it is not retrieving the data

`SELECT * FROM school Where '4059' IN school.lineHaulLmr[*].driverDetails.sloc`

Comment: its eloc in the query.

Comment: If you're trying to search in an array check this https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/arrayfun.html

Comment: Its not addresing the issuing i ma facing. I have check on before hand.

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: Its not retrieving the data which I actually want

Comment: The above question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all thanks for the response. I got the query and it looks like this
SELECT * FROM School where '4059' in School .lineHaulLmr[*].driverDetails[*].sloc

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM school Where driverDetails.sloc = '8585'
```

Comment: It doesnt give any result VHS

Comment: oops, sloc is a subfield. Use the . notation and try again.

Comment: @Sree, did you try `SELECT * FROM school Where driverDetails.sloc = '8585'`

Comment: driverDetails json is in the array lineHaulLmr so it doesnt give resultset with the above query too. I tried it too